# Non-linear counter

Tags: algorithm, math, counter, nonlinear-functions

So I have a counter. It is supposed to calculate the current amount of something. To calculate this, I know the start date, and start amount, and the amount to increment the counter by each second. Easy peasy. The tricky part is that the growth is not quite linear. Every day, the increment amount increases by a set amount. I need to recreate this algorithmically - basically figure out the exact value at the current date based on the starting value, the amount incremented over time, and the amount the increment has increased over time.

My target language is Javascript, but pseudocode is fine too.

Based on AB's solution:

```
var now = new Date();

var startDate1 = new Date("January 1 2010");
var days1 = (now - startDate1) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
var startNumber1 = 9344747520;
var startIncrement1 = 463;
var dailyIncrementAdjustment1 = .506;
var currentIncrement = startIncrement1 + (dailyIncrementAdjustment1 * days1);

startNumber1 = startNumber1 + (days1 / 2) * (2 * startIncrement1 + (days1 - 1) * dailyIncrementAdjustment1);
```

Does that look reasonable to you guys?

Comment: And I bet you thought that all those calculus classes would be useless...

Comment: @Ignacio: since when do you need calculus to recognize an arithmetic progression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a quadratic function. If `t` is the time passed, then it's the usual at<sup>2</sup>+bt+c, and you can figure out `a,b,c` by substituting the results for the first 3 seconds.

Or: use the formula for the [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) sum, where `a1` is the initial increment, and `d` is the "set amount" you refer to. Just don't forget to add your "start amount" to what the formula gives you.

If x<sub>0</sub> is the initial amount, d is the initial increment, and e is the "set amount" to increase the incerement, it comes to 
x<sub>0</sub> + (t/2)*(2d + (t-1)*e)

Comment: Does the arithmetic progression solution only work for discreet increases? The way I worded my question implies that this is indeed what I was looking for, but if the increase occurs continuously throughout the day, and not in a discreet step each day, then something tells me that I'd need to use a different formula. A colleague suggested an integral of some kind, but my mathematical background is insufficient to make any initial judgment as to that solution's potential efficacy.

Thank you for your assistance,
Patrick

Comment: @uncultured: You pretty much answered your own question. When you move from a discrete setting to continuous, sums are replaced by integrals, and differences by derivatives. The rest depends very much on the particulars of your case.

Comment: Thanks again. I think the arithmetic progression solution will be more than sufficient for my needs. These numbers are marketing, not scientific or mission critical, so creating a perfect analog to reality is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have an initial value `x_0`, an initial increment per second of `d_0` and an increment adjustment of `e` per day. That is, on day one the increment per second is `d_0`, on day two the increment per second is `d_0 + e`, etc.

Then, we note that the increment per second at time `t` is

```
d(t) = d_0 + floor(t / S) * e
```

where `S` is the number of seconds per day and `t` is the number of seconds that have elapsed since `t = t_0`. Then

```
x = x_0 + sum_{k < floor(t / S)} S * d(k) + S * (t / S - floor(t / S)) * d(t)
```

is the formula that you are seeking. From here, you can simplify this to

```
x = x_0 + S * floor(t / S) d_0 + S * e * (floor(t / S) - 1) * floor(t / S) / 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $start = 0;
my $stop = 100;
my $current = $start;

for my $day ( 1 ..  100 ) {
    $current += ($day / 10);
    last unless $current < $stop;
    printf "Day: %d\tLeft %.2f\n", $day, (1 - $current/$stop);
}
```

Output:

```
Day: 1  Left 1.00
Day: 2  Left 1.00
Day: 3  Left 0.99
Day: 4  Left 0.99
Day: 5  Left 0.98
...
Day: 42 Left 0.10
Day: 43 Left 0.05
Day: 44 Left 0.01
```